# Make GNU ld or GNU gold show which .o files in an archive are used

Tags: linux, debugging, linker

I'm trying to link a C++ binary, but I get undefined symbol errors. My binary shouldn't need those symbols, and I'd like to understand the dependency chain causing the linker (GNU ld or GNU gold) think that they are needed. There is `libfoo.a` containing hundreds of `.o` files. My program is calling function in `libfoo.a`. I'd like to get a dependency graph containing all `.o` files in `libfoo.a` which the linker thinks are needed to link my program.

I need it because I suspect that there is a mistake somewhere in `libfoo.a`, calling functions which are not really needed. I can modify the source code of `libfoo.a` (and thus remove the unneeded calls), and for that I need to understand where the unneeded calls are. The dependency graph could help me find it.

Please note that there is no resulting executable, because of the undefined symbols.

Please note that my ultimate goal is not to build this particular binary, but to make sure that unneeded functions are not called in `libfoo.a`.

I've looked at `man ld`, but I couldn't find any command-line flag that could give me more verbose output.

Example error from the linker:

```
libfoo++.a(foo1.o):foo1.cc:function foo1f: error: undefined reference to 'bar'
```

How do I figure out what caused `foo1.o` to be linked to the executable? (It's OK for me that `bar` is undefined, because I don't need it. My problem is that `foo1.o` is needed, but it shouldn't be, and I'd like to remove the call which caused `foo1.o` to be linked in.)

Comment: Why don't you make a `libfoo.so` shared library?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Adding dynamic linking support to my platform would be way too much work. Why do you think that building `libfoo.so` would help me find what I want?

Comment: Have you tried using --as-needed?  If the linker says you've got unresolved symbols, it's probably correct. :D (edit: this is RE: your ultimate goal, not the actual question)

Comment: @nevelis: How would `--as-needed` help me find the offending function call? Yes, the linker is correct, but there is a bug in `libfoo.a`, because its source code contains an unnecessary function call. My goal is to find this function call, study it, and remove it. I'm asking for help to find it.

Comment: @pts - my bad, that's the fault of 4am vision.. :D In your statement "make sure that unneeded functions are not called", I read "not called" as "not linked", and was trying to help with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to get a dependency graph containing all .o files in libfoo.a which the linker thinks are needed to link my program.

The linker map, printed with `-M` (or `--print-map`) flag contains exactly that info. If you are using compiler driver (e.g. `gcc`) to perform the link (you should), then add `-Wl,-M` to the link line.

Comment: Exactly, this map is printed to the stdout, and it starts with the `Archive member included because of file (symbol)` section, exactly what I am interested in. Answer accepted.